# how to store access token in http-only cookies with app router in next js 14 api

Tags: authentication, jwt, http-headers, next.js13, cookie-httponly

hi there im working on next js app and i've created login api. In that api im creating jwt token and i want to set this token to http-only cookies and send json response to user that logged in successfully
here is my code...

```
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"; // Import jsonwebtoken library
import prismaClient from "../../../../../prisma/prismaClient";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import vine, { errors } from "@vinejs/vine";
import { loginValidation } from "../../../../../vineValidation/validation";
import JSONAPIErrorReporter from "../../../../../vineValidation/errorReporter";

export async function POST(req, res) {
  const data = await req.json();
  const validator = vine.compile(loginValidation);
  validator.errorReporter = () => new JSONAPIErrorReporter();
  let user;
  try {
    await validator.validate(data);
    try {
      switch (data.role) {
        case "teacher":
          user = await prismaClient.Teacher.findUnique({
            where: { email: data.email, role: data.role },
          });
          break;
        case "admin":
          user = await prismaClient.Admin.findUnique({
            where: { email: data.email, role: data.role },
          });
          break;
        case "student":
          user = await prismaClient.Student.findUnique({
            where: { email: data.email, role: data.role },
          });
          break;
        default:
          return NextResponse.json({ error: "Invalid userType", status: 404 });
      }

      if (!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(data.password, user.hashedPassword)) {
        return NextResponse.json({
          error: "Incorrect Email Or Password",
          status: 404,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return NextResponse.json({
        error: "Database Connection Error",
        status: 500,
        msg: error.message,
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof errors.E_VALIDATION_ERROR) {
      return NextResponse.json({
        error: "Validation error",
        errorMessage: error.messages,
        status: error.status,
      });
    } else {
      console.log(error.messages);
      return NextResponse.json({
        error: error.message,
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  }

  // Get the secret key from environment variable
  const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

  // Create a token with the user data and the secret key
  const token = jwt.sign(user, secret);

  return NextResponse.json({
    message: "Logged In Successfully",
    status: 200,
    token,
  });
}
type here
```

i've tried this method too

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Your existing code for handling the POST request
  res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    `accessToken=${token}; HttpOnly; Path=/; Max-Age=3600; SameSite=Strict`
  );

  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Logged In Successfully",
    token, // Send the token back to the client as a response
  });
}
```

but i think in next 13/14 this method not working and got this error

```
⨯ Detected default export in 'D:\work space\pak millat\pak-millat\src\app\api\user\login\route.js'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
 ⨯ TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/login/route.js:88:9)
    at async D:\work space\pak millat\pak-millat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251
 ⨯ TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/login/route.js:88:9)
    at async D:\work space\pak millat\pak-millat\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63251
```